# Jquery hover animation stops working after clicking on another link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

The issue is when I load the page the first time, the animate effect works.  However when I click on another link, even one that goes back to this same page, the animation no longer works when I hover.  It will work again if I reload the page.

Any ideas why??

I have this JQuery script in my Rails application's app/assets/javascripts/comics.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".comic-container").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.comic-info-hidden').animate({
        height: '100%'
    }, 200);
 },function(){
    $(this).find('.comic-info-hidden').animate({
        height: '0%'
    }, 300);
 });
});
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

relevant gems in Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using turbolinks. Turbo links will update the body with the required view, but not the jquery events when you change pages. You can use jquery turbolinks to help with this.

https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks